# In a Pinescript v5 Strategy why is my bool not working?

Tags: boolean, tradingview-api

I'm having trouble with this bool in my pinescript strategy. Basically it won't remember the state for whatever reason.

```
var bool inTrade = false
// LONG
if inTradeWindow and src > upper2 and src > kc_upper and src < closetooFarLongPricePercent and useRSI and rsi > rsiLongLower and rsi < rsiLongUpper
    if inTrade
        strategy.close('Exit Short')
        strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, alert_message = reversalLongMessage, comment = "Reversal Long "+ str.tostring(inTrade) + "Trade num " + str.tostring(tradeNum))
        tradeNum := tradeNum + 1
    if not inTrade
        inTrade := true
        strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, alert_message = goLongMessage, comment = "New Long "+ str.tostring(inTrade) + "Trade num " + str.tostring(tradeNum))
        tradeNum := tradeNum + 1
// Exit by Lookback and %
if inTradeWindow and stopTypeLong == "%" and inTrade == true
    stopPriceLongTrail = stopSrcLong * (1 - stopLossPercentLongTrail / 100)
    inTrade := false
    strategy.exit('Stop Loss Long Trail', 'Long', stop=stopPriceLongTrail, alert_message = stopLongMessage, comment = "SL Long "+ str.tostring(inTrade))
```

The short conditions are basically the same so no need to clutter with masses of code. I also exploded out the if inTrade from the main if statement whilst trying to troubleshoot but I originally just had it as an "and" and " and not" for the reversal and new trades respectively.

So for whatever reason I'm unable to fathom, this inTrade var doesn't persist or isn't being checked correctly by TV as if I remove the and inTrade == true from the SL code I get my SL's triggered. But what's weird is I have them printing to comments on the chart trades. The value is set correctly before the execution of the strategy.entry/exit. See images and comments on each image below.

[image: With inTrade == true on SL, All trades should be reversals as in this example no trade before was closed by a SL and so inTrade should remain true, If you look at the comments on each trade you will see the word New Long/Short true. This should read Reversal true.]

[image: Here I removed the SL inTrade condition and highlight the trades. You can clearly see that when SL is hit inTrade is false, the next Long is correct (but not really), as it is a New Long true, but immediately after it, the next 2 trades are a New Short true and a New Long true, which should be a Reversal true.]

Image 1: With inTrade == true on SL, All trades should be reversals as in this example no trade before was closed by a SL and so inTrade should remain true, If you look at the comments on each trade you will see the word New Long/Short true. This should read Reversal true.

Image 2: Here I removed the SL inTrade condition and highlight the trades. You can clearly see that when SL is hit inTrade is false, the next Long is correct (but not really), as it is a New Long true, but immediately after it, the next 2 trades are a New Short true and a New Long true, which should be a Reversal true.

So where I thought I was going mad, I tried to use an input.bool() for inTrade, and low and behold, both pieces of code work. If I tick the box, I only get reversals, if I untick the box I only get New's!

Conclusion... Bool not working???

Someone please shed some light here, is it me or a limitiation of TV?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your complete code it is really hard to help you.
I suppose there is a misconception in your code : opening a long when a short is already on will close the short and place the long and vice-versa, but it is hard to tell without looking at all the code.
Then your strategy seems to run as you code it :

1. inTrade is false
2. your conditions are met, as Intrade=false, Intrade becomes true
3. then it enter the SL part, set an exit position and Intrade becomes false : but at this point, your trade is certainly still on (The SL is not yet hit).

On the next bar, a new loop for your script, inTrade=false (from bullet 3 before) and then your script think that not trades is on.
Perhaps you should replace
**Intrade** with

```
strategy.opentrades != 0
```

and replace
not(Intrade) with

```
strategy.opentrades == 0
```

Comment: Thanks G. haven't tested it yet but that might be the thing i'm missing, whasn't previously aware of the opentrades piece of strategy. 

I have to do it this way as I need to send 2 different messages to my broker for the different cases, reverse or stop. will let you know if it works.

Comment: Yep Just tested it now, works perfectly. at least on the chart. Thanks again Mr. G